# ESR of X2 RFI suppression film capacitors

Tags: capacitor, esr

I came across a DUAL 1209 turntable and it is equipped with an old 0.1 μF, 275 V RFI suppression capacitor. This thing is not X2 rated or anything, and I am not sure if it is still good, as it is about 50 years old.

The capacity is about spot-on, the capacitor does not show continuity (I can't measure leakage current though), but what baffles me is that my ESR meter shows > 100 Ω.

I got a couple more 10 nF X1 caps lying around I salvaged from old parts and they also show > 100 Ω, but I got some fairly new 47 nF X2 caps which show just about 20 Ω or less of ESR at 100 kHz.

What should be the typical ESR value for an X2 capacitor? Is it normal that they could be above 100 Ω or are they kinda "gone"?

Comment: What ESR meter?

Comment: It's a cheap chinese product called MESR-100

Comment: Manual says error in small values is expected: https://www.gotronik.pl/images/mesr100-maual.pdf

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out ! I put two in parallel and now the meter shows 100 Ohm. Well, i'll just replace it and have the new one X2 rated.